# Using methods in other files

Tags: ruby

there are two ruby files rubyA and rubyB. rubyB contains just 2 methods

```
#rubyB.rb
def foo1()
   p "foo1 from rubyB"
end 
def foo2()
   foo1()
end
```

and rubyA contains

```
#rubyA.rb
require_relative 'rubyB.rb'
def foo1()
   p "foo1 from rubyA"
end
foo2()
```

the output will be "foo1 from rubyA". 
How can foo2 call foo1 from his file and not from the other?

Comment: Did you get warnings. Try again with `ruby -w`

Comment: I am not clear.. I am getting the output as *"foo1 from rubyA"*..

Comment: @ArupRakshit OP probably expected it to be `"foo1 from rubyB"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#rubyB.rb
class B
  def self.foo1
   p "foo from B"
  end
  def self.foo2
    foo1
  end
end

#rubyA.rb
class A
  def self.foo1
    p "foo from A"
  end
  def self.foo2
    foo1
  end
end

#mycode.rb
require_relative 'rubyA'
require_relative 'rubyB'

B.foo2
```

Answer (score 2):

you just overrided it! You cant have 2 methods with the same name in the same "scope".

You might want to use classes or modules to scope your methods.

Also, the behaviour of require_relative is almost like having all the code from the required file in the place you required it. So its basically the same of having this file.

```
# require_relative 'rubyB.rb'

def foo1
   p "foo1 from rubyB"
end 
def foo2
   foo1
end 

def foo1
   p "foo1 from rubyA"
end
foo2
```

Answer (score 1):

Both files are working in the global namespace.  You can modify both files to use modules to specify a namespace

```
# rubyB.rb
module RubyB
  def self.foo1
    p "foo1 from rubyB"
  end
  def self.foo2
    foo1
  end
end

# rubyA.rb
require_relative 'rubyB'
module RubyA
  def self.foo1
    p "foo1 from rubyA"
  end
end
RubyB.foo2
```

The self. before a method defines it as a module method and can be called within the modules namespace. (As we do on the last line, with `RubyB.foo2`.  When RubyB.foo2 gets called, control jumps into the RubyB module, where the RubyB namespace in already included.  Thus the call to `foo1`, automatically calls `RubyB.foo1`.

Read more [here](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/35-modules/lessons/80-modules-as-namespaces), it was one of the first hits when I googled 'ruby module as a namespace'